# No user identified in an answer to this question

Tags: discussion

[How do I pass multiple commands to START in Windows Command Line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1680186/how-do-i-pass-multiple-commands-to-start-in-windows-command-line)

no user or options to close, edit etc, whats the deal? No direct link to share either.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Could be a site glitch with being read-only? There has been a bit of downtime lately...

Comment: @moab Working fine for me - although the page took a long time to load.

Comment: Yep, its fixed, feel free to close the question